# Evaluating a line integral for a vector field and a path C

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

$$F(x,y)=\langle 2y^2+y^2\cos(xy^2),4xy+2xy\cos(xy^2)\rangle $$
$$r(t)=\langle e^t\sin(t),e^t\cos(t)\rangle,\quad  t\in[0,\pi].$$

I found $$r'(t)= \langle \left[ e^t\sin(t) + e^t\cos(t) \right] \, dt, \left[ e^t \cos(t) - e^t\sin(t)\right] \, dt \rangle .$$

Now I know $\int_0^\pi F\cdot dr$, so I thought I substitute $e^t\sin(t)$ for $x$ and $e^t\cos(t)$ for $y$ and multiply by their respective $r(t)$ value, but the integral gets lengthy and complex very quickly. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Your $r'(t)$ is not right because you have to use the product rule. Also, there should not be $dt$'s after each component in $r'(t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They gave you a nightmarish integral on purpose. You were supposed to notice that $F$ is conservative. Then $F=\nabla f$ for some function $f$ and 
$$
\int_C F\cdot d\vec r=f(\vec r(\pi))-f(\vec r(0)).
$$